# JavaScript not working in Firefox

Tags: javascript

Hi ' im having a problem with my script in firefox, i'm getting the fault , " window.event is undefined " , where seems to be the problem?

```
<script language="JavaScript1.2"> 

function formattel(){

 var value = document.formkkush.telefoon.value; 
 var valueLen = document.formkkush.telefoon.value.length; 

 if(valueLen>2 && valueLen<4) 
 { 
 if(window.event.keyCode==8) 
 document.formkkush.telefoon.value=document.formkkush.telefoon.value.remove(valueLen-1,1); 
 else 
 document.formkkush.telefoon.value=document.formkkush.telefoon.value+"/"; 
 }
 if(valueLen>5 && valueLen<7) 
 { 
 if(window.event.keyCode==8) 
 document.formkkush.telefoon.value=document.formkkush.telefoon.value.remove(valueLen-1,1); 
 else 
 document.formkkush.telefoon.value=document.formkkush.telefoon.value+"."; 
 }
 if(valueLen>8 && valueLen<10) 
 { 
 if(window.event.keyCode==8) 
 document.formkkush.telefoon.value=document.formkkush.telefoon.value.remove(valueLen-1,1); 
 else 
 document.formkkush.telefoon.value=document.formkkush.telefoon.value+"."; 
 }
}
```

Comment: Is that script tag actually closed and you didn't paste it? Don't use the `language` attribute, which is deprecated. Javascript script tags should include a MIME-type: `<script type="application/javascript"> ... </script>`. And why are you using/specifying Javascript 1.2? That's from 1997.

Answer (score 3):

The global event object isn't created in Firefox.  It's instead passed as the first argument in the event handler's function.

```
function formattel(eventObj){ 
  var value = document.formkkush.telefoon.value;  
  var valueLen = document.formkkush.telefoon.value.length;  

  // Make sure we have the even object no matter which browser we're running on
  eventObj = eventObj || window.event;

  if(valueLen>2 && valueLen<4)  
  {  
    if(eventObj.keyCode==8)  
      document.formkkush.telefoon.value=document.formkkush.telefoon.value.remove(valueLen-1,1);  
    else  
      document.formkkush.telefoon.value=document.formkkush.telefoon.value+"/";  
  } 
  // etc...
}
```

See the Mozilla documentation for [event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event).

As a completely unrelated suggestion, you should try and lessen the number of DOM node lookups by setting repeated lookups to a variable.  It makes your code faster and much more presentable:

```
function formattel(eventObj){ 

  var telefoon = document.formkkush.telefoon; 
  var value = telefoon.value;  
  var valueLen = value.length;  

  // Make sure we have the even object no matter which browser we're running on
  eventObj = eventObj || window.event;

  if(valueLen>2 && valueLen<4)  
  {  
    if(eventObj.keyCode==8)  
      telefoon.value = telefoon.value.remove(valueLen-1,1);  
    else  
      telefoon.value += "/";  
  } 
  // etc...
}
```

Don't forget about assignment operators (such as `+=`) too!

Comment: @Dave: no need to apologise :-) The answer I posted is the correct way of handling the event object if the function `formattel` is the event handler of the function.  Read the Mozilla documentation for event that I posted and it should help you work out where you're going wrong.

Comment: don't forget to check for a window.event object, too.

Comment: @Dave: here's a nice article about the event object in different browsers: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_properties.html

Comment: @Marcel: Good point, I was concentrating on making sure the code was OK for Firefox lol.  Nice link too, I've spent a good few hours of my coding life on Quirksmode.